# How can I print a part of a list depending on various conditions?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I want 2 conditions to be met

I have 2 lists
Height(Estatura): [1.60,1.98,1.70,1.611.80,1.72 ...]

Age(Edad): [6,10,15,78,23,21...]

this is a part the csv  :

[image]

this is my code i can read csv :

```
def abrir_csv(Doc):
    with open(Doc, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lector = csv.reader(f)
        next(lector)
        contenido = [Almacenamiento_de_datos(Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO,
                                             float(Estatura), int(Edad), Fecha) for
                     Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO, Estatura, Edad, Fecha in
                     lector]
        return contenido
```

I want a part of the height list where it starts at between 1.60 and 1.90 but starting from the age of 15 to 30 years
and try print this code :

```
def MAXEDAD(Doc): #Valor Maximo y Minimo
    Estatura = {s.Estatura > 1.65 <= 1.80 for s, x in Doc if x.Edad > 15 < 30}
    A = [sorted(Estatura)]
    return A
```

but i have a error:

```
    Estatura = {s.Estatura > 1.65 <= 1.80 for s, x in Doc if x.Edad > 15 < 30}
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can print fulfilling various conditionals.
thanks

Comment: What is `Doc`? You need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, and expected output. It also wouldn't hurt to include the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: BTW, `x > 1.65 <= 1.80` doesn't really make sense. You probably want `1.65 < x <= 1.80`.

Comment: Doc = is my csv when i call

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I just edited my above comment to clarify. You need to include `Doc` itself. Like, we need to know what type it is and what it contains, in order to make sense of the error you're getting.

Comment: The error means that each row of `Doc` has more than 2 items in it.

Comment: yes  sorry  my mistake, i edited the post  :)

Comment: Also `x.Edad > 15 < 30` should be `15 < x.Edad < 30`

Comment: @CrisdaxMusicInfinity You still haven't shown an example of your CSV.

Comment: A CSV file just contains strings, not objects. Where do the `Estatura` and `Edad` attributes come from?

Comment: You say you have two lists. The code never uses those lists, what do they have to do with it?

Comment: they are lists of tuples what I understand when one reads the csv file

Comment: I edited the post, in this post there is a picture of my csv

Comment: If you're using `csv.reader()`, each row is a tuple. Each field in the row is an element of the tuple. There are no named attributes. You need to convert the strings to numbers before you can compare them.

Comment: 1) thanks for arrange my image  
2 ) Well, I have already been able to compare with a condition, but I don't know how I can with several conditions within the same list.

Comment: @barmar yes yes i have convert numbers : `  contenido = [Almacenamiento_de_datos(Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO,
                                             float(Estatura), int(Edad), Fecha) for.... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `csv.reader()` to read the CSV, you need to assign to enough variables to get each field, not just two fields. The fields are just strings, not objects with attributes. You could also use `csv.DictReader()` to convert the rows to dictionaries whose keys are the field names from the header row.

If you want to test multiple conditions, use `and` to combine them. And you need to convert the values to numbers before comparing them to numbers.

```
def MAXEDAD(Doc): #Valor Maximo y Minimo
    Estatura = [estatura for tipo, nombres, genero, cuerpo, distrito, denuncia, estatua, eda, fecha in Doc 
        if 1.65 < float(estatura) < 1.80 and 15 < int(edad)  < 30]
    return sorted(Estatura)
```

There's no need to put a list around `sorted(Estatura)`

Comment: ufff no work for example : is other code : `def Filtrar_Contenido (Doc): #filtrar contenido
    Nombres =[s.Distrito for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "fat"]
    Respuesta = [len(Nombres)]
    return Respuesta`                                                                                                                       . I can't put 2 conditions into a list?

Comment: Why are you still using `s.XXX`? They're not objects, they're tuples.

Comment: `s.Distrito` should be `s[4]`

Comment: Maybe you should use Pandas.

Comment: for iterable and it works i dont know,  i am noob in this wonderful world python ....i know i have this s.Edad i can Iterable ....you want see How do I read the csv?

Comment: yes pandas is better but i need without libraries external.

Comment: If you're using `csv.reader()` this should work.

Comment: jajajaj...yes and no  one moment i need edit my post one moment , and thanks for helpme

Comment: What you have expressed to me during this help is that I cannot put 2 conditions in a list, right? I better see another method? I dont know
if s. Height> 1.60 <1.90:
if Age 5 <10:
(code)

Comment: Of course you can, see my code.